# Absolute element inheriting relative parent div's width

Tags: css, nested, parent-child, css-position

I am trying to position a gradient over an inline / inline-block anchor link, and have that gradient inherit the width of that parent anchor. The problem is that the span either inherits the entire width of the anchor's parent, or just the width of the &nbsp;. I am unable to get the span element to properly inherit the width while maintaining the anchors inline display.

CSS

```
a { width: auto; display: inline-block; }

a span { background: url(../images/fade_h1.png); width: 100%; height: 12px; position: absolute; display: block; z-index: 3; }
```

HTML

```
<a href="index.php"><span>&nbsp;</span>Index</a>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Can't be done with `position: absolute` as far as I can see.

I'm not sure whether this will serve you, but how about giving the `a` `position: relative` and the `a span`

```
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
top: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
```

?

Comment: @abysslogic no, I mean setting only the parent to `relative` but leaving the child `absolute`, that should make the child take up the same space as the parent (if that's what you want.)

Comment: oh weird, I thought relative positioning was automatic - didnt know I had to define it in my code. That solved it, thanks!

Comment: It's called conflicting absolute positions: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/conflictingabsolutepositions/

Comment: Oh WOW, I didn't know relative positioning had to be defined specifically, either.  Thanks for this answer!

Comment: For those who think `relative` positioning is default, the default is actually `static` positioning